# A two dimensional range in a three dimensional array

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on several sheets where there are different size of tables. I would like to use a single variable to gather all those information.

Here is my code for the moment :

```
ReDim temp(1 To NbSheets)
for i = 1 to NbSheets
    Set rt = Wb.Sheets(i).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    temp(i) = rt
Next i
```

With this code, temp contains all the information but it is still a one dimension-array.

How can I put those ranges in the variable and call the value temp(x,y,z)?

Thank you for your help !

Oliver

Edit :

For more information, here is the code more detailed.

```
MyPath = "Y:\"
PPMelem = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*", vbDirectory)

ReDim temp(1 To NbSheets)


'Loop to open all the files
While PPMelem <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & PPMelem, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True
    Set WbElem = ActiveWorkbook

    LastCol = WbElem.Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
    LastRow = WbElem.Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row


    'A range with all the information and I put in the variable
    Set rt = WbElem.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    temp(NumFile) = rt

    WbElem.Close False

    PPMelem = Dir
Wend
```

And this what it returns [I have a one-dimension array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRgnw.jpg)

[But in each part there is a range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2BP9.jpg)

Comment: What's `x`, `y`, and `z`? Your question is unclear, you're not iterating rows and columns anywhere, just sheets. Have you tried declaring `temp` as a 3D array? What part are you stumped at specifically?

Comment: ^^ And what is going in this "3rd" dimension?

Comment: x = sheets
y = rows
z = columns

I'd like to avoid iterating rows and columns because it would take to much time I think.

My problem is that I can't specifically call one single piece of information, I can only call the whole sheet

Comment: You have an array of arrays (or a 1d array of 2d arrays). You should still be able to access by position temp(1)(1,1) or some such.

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. Thank you very much, somehow that answers my question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

As QHarr said :
temp is an array of arrays. So I can access by position with temp(1)(1,1)